# Construction of real numbes

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

How do I prove that the set of real numbers is the set of the power set of the set of natural numbers ?

I can understand that the set of reals is uncountable and the set of Natural Numbers is countable. But I am trying to get a construction of real numbers from the set of natural numbers or may be even ration numbers that clearly shows that the set of Real numbers is a power set.

Is there any such construction ?

Comment: To prove such a thing, you first need a definition of $\mathbb R$, which you haven't provided. In any case, any reasonable definition of $\mathbb R$ will **not** be such that $\mathbb R=\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb N))$ due to cardinality issues.

Comment: I am not trying to get R = P(P(N)). I just want a construction such that R = P(N) as per the cardinalities say. Sorry but i don't know how to enter text in Latex. @GitGud

Comment: If you can define $\mathbb{R}$ as the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{R}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ then you have a problem with cardinality. The equality it is independent of ZFC as shwon by Godel and Cohen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Comment: @mfl: That's simply not true. In many places in set theory the real numbers are considered as the set $2^\Bbb N$. In other places, $\Bbb{N^N}$, and sometimes it's another thing altogether which is more akin to the "usual" real numbers.

Comment: @mfl: No it's not. $|\mathbb R|=2^{|\mathbb N|}$ independently of the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: The most common (at least the one I've seen the most) definition of the reals, does construct the as sets of other numbers (not the naturals, I won't tell you which set), but only some sets of those so the reals are not the power set.

Comment: @Henrik Just because it doesn't contain all the same things doesn't mean that it doesn't have the same cardinality. After all, the rationals are countable (the same cardinality as $\Bbb{N}$) despite the fact that *almost all* rational numbers are not natural numbers.

Comment: I would imagine that you would constuct a bijection between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{N}$ so that you can express subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ as subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$. Then you could set up a bijection between infinite subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$ and *sequences* of rationals--in particular, Cauchy sequences. This is, of course, assuming that you are using Cauchy sequences to construct the reals. You could do a similar process with Dedekind cuts, though.

Comment: @KSmarts: I didn't say anything about cardinality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be very unusual to set up things such that the set of real numbers **is the same set** as $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

What you can do -- in several different ways -- is to show that there is a *bijection* between the two sets. One fairly painless way is to start by knowing that $\mathbb Q$ is countable such that there is a surjection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$. We can then define injections $g:\mathbb R\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and $h:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb R$:

$$ g(x) = \{ n\in\mathbb N \mid f(n)<x \} $$
$$ h(A) = \sum_{n\in A} 10^{-n} $$

and then appeal to the [Schröder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) to get a *bijection* $\psi:\mathbb R\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

---

If you *really* want $\mathbb R$ to be **the same set** as $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, then the easiest things to do is probably to start with one of the standard constructions of the reals (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences), but call what you're constructing the something else, e.g. the "proto-reals" $\hat {\mathbb R}$. Then do as above to get a bijection $\hat\psi : \hat{\mathbb R}\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, and make $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ into a field by defining:

$$ A + B = \hat\psi(\hat\psi{}^{-1}(A) \, \hat+\, \hat\psi{}^{-1}(B)) $$
$$ A \times B = \hat\psi(\hat\psi{}^{-1}(A) \,\hat\times\, \hat\psi{}^{-1}(B)) $$

Then $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ with these operations will have all of the properties we usually expect the reals to have.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is *very* unusual. We do it all the time in set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I thought you were simply being sloppy using the same word for the power set and the field, depending on context.

Comment: No, consider the Cohen forcing, as the tree $2^{<\omega}$, its generic is a new branch which defines a new subset of $\Bbb N$. And we say that this new subset is "a Cohen real".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Again, my impression (from the outside) was that this is simply an alternative use of the word "real" that is convenient in the set-theory context.

Comment: Well, if you dismiss their field structure, then what are the reals? Just a set. Why not *this* set? Not to mention that it's a lovely topological space, which usually means more to us (even to non-set theorists!).